# Prove that if $N(z)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}$ then $z$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{\alpha}]$.

Tags: number-theory

Let $\alpha\in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $\sqrt{\alpha}\notin{\Bbb{Q}}$, and let $N:\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{\alpha}]\to \Bbb{Z}$ be the norm function. Prove that if $N(z)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}$ then $z$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{\alpha}]$.

What I did so far is: Let $z=a+b\sqrt{\alpha}.$ Then $N(z)=a^2-\alpha b^2$. I am having trouble making conclusions so as to find out things about $z$ itself.

The definition I was given: **An element in a ring $A$ is called "irreducible" if its divisors are associated to it or are reversible.**

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $N$ is multiplicative, i.e. $N(z_1z_2)=N(z_1)N(z_2)$. If $z$ is reducible in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{\alpha}]$, then $z=z_1z_2$ for some nonunits $z_1,z_2\in\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{\alpha}]$. Thus, $N(z)=N(z_1)N(z_2)$. But $z_1$ and $z_2$ are nonunits, so their norm is not $\pm1$, so $N(z)$ is reducible in $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: What does it mean in this theory, "nonunits"? Excuse my ignorance, but I have not studied it in English and therefore my lexics are lacking.

Comment: For a ring $R$, $r\in R$ is a unit if $\exists s\in R$ such that $rs=sr=1$. An element in a ring is irreducible if it is not the product of two nonunits.

Comment: How shall I show equivalence between the definition you use and the one I wrote?
Maybe you might know...

Comment: In an integral domain $R$, $r,s\in R$ are associates iff $r=su$ for some unit $u\in R$. If $r$ divides $z$, $rs=z$ for some $s$. By my definition, if $z$ is irreducible, either $r$ or $s$ is a unit. So $r|z$ implies $r$ is a unit or $r$ is an associate of $z$.

Answer (score 2):

We know  $z=a+b\sqrt\alpha$ is a unit if an only if $N(z)=a^2-\alpha b^2$ is a unit in $\mathbf Z$.

From this basic fact we deduce that if $N(z)$ is irreducible, then $z$ is irreducible. We'll prove this by contraposition: if $z$ is reducible as $z=st$, $s,t$  non-units,  by the multiplicative property of the norm:
$$N(z)=N(s)N(t),\quad N(s)N(u)\neq\pm 1$$
so that $N(z)$ is reducible in $\mathbf Z$.